# Semantic is consuming all CPU, causing emacs to hang

Tags: windows, emacs

I upgraded to emacs 23.2.1 on Windows 7, not long ago.

Since then I've been unable to use Semantic. 
As soon as I start it, the cpu goes to MAX . (actually, Windows reports it at 50%, but this is a dual core machine, so emacs is effectively consuming 100% of a core).
Emacs becomes non-responsive.

Is there a particular combination of versions of semantic and emacs I that is unsafe to use together?

how would I debug this spin/hang?

I've seen other suggestions to change the `semantic-idle-scheduler-idle-time`, from its default 2 to something very large.  I tried that, but got the same results.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is being voted to be closed.  Seems like a fair question to me.  If this is a repeat, please direct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was using the "old" cedet+semantic. I did not realize (or maybe I forgot) that cedet was included in emacs v23.2.  When I fixed up my load-path to ignore the cedet I had separately downloaded, the spin went away.

I guess you could call this a case of "EL Hell".